# How to restrict file format?

Tags: jquery

Below I have a jquery code which includes a textbox where the user can choose a file:

```
var $imagefile = $('<input />')
    .attr({
        type: 'file',
        name: 'imageFile',
        id: 'imageFile'
    });
```

What my question is that how can I get it so that it restricts the user from picking jpeg, gif or png files? I want user to browse for a file, then click on the submit button. If the file type is correct then show confirmation message else display an alert stating "Wrong file format has been chosen for the Image".

Below is the validation() where it displays the alerts:

```
function validation() {

    var marks = parseInt($("#total-weight").text());    
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    var maxQuestions = <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>;
    var questionsAdded = $('tr.optionAndAnswer').length;


    var alertValidation = "";
    // Note, this is just so it's declared...
    $("tr.optionAndAnswer").each(function() {


        _qid = $("td.qid",this).text();
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";

        $(".textAreaQuestion",this).each(function() {



            if (!this.value || this.value.length < 5) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered a valid Question\n";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }
        });


        $(".txtWeightRow",this).each(function() {


            if (!this.value) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 Please enter in a figure for Number of Marks for this Question\n";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }
        });


        if(alertValidation != ""){
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: match the selected file name to a regex pattern like (.+\.jpg$|.+\.png$|.+\.gif$|.+\.jpeg$) if it matches inform the usr to pick again

Comment: You shouldn't change the `type` attribute of an element after you create it, IE will give you problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<input type="file">` has long (since it was introduced in 1995) had an `accept` attribute, where you can list MIME-types that you want to accept, e.g. `accept="image/*"`. It's only *very* recently that browsers have started to support it, though. Right now, Opera 11, Chrome 16, Firefox 9. IE doesn't.

Can't recall whether the use of `accept` actually filters the files listed in the file selection dialog box, or just restricts the files accepted *after* the user has selected them. May vary from browser to browser and OS to OS.

But yes, you can check the file extension after the file has been selected. Something like (untested):

```
var allowedTypes = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"];

var path = $imagefile.val();
var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

if ($.inArray(ext, allowedTypes) < 0) {
   alertValidation += '\n\u2022 Unsupported file type';
}
```

In any event, you'll want to validate the file types on the server, and not depend on the client to ensure they're the right type.

Comment: Is there a way checking it server side, so that when I click on submit button it checks on server side and if its fine submit, else show alert?

Comment: You'll have to upload the file to the server in order to have the server check it, then let the server send an error message back if invalid file types have posted. The client validation is only a convenience for the user (not making him have to upload files that would never be accepted by the server), but a malicious user can easily cheat any client side check.

Comment: I found an example in W3schools and made the application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Files/Files.html), Can you do this for me, is there a way it will display a alert on the page but still do the server side check, instead of going onto a new page showing the server side details of the flle?

Comment: See edited answer. Only an example, probably doesn't follow your code so far *exactly*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute `accept="image/*"` to your `input` tag, as

```
var $imagefile = $('<input />')
    .attr({
        type: 'file',
        name: 'imageFile',
        id: 'imageFile',
        accept: 'image/*'
    });
```

You should double check on the server side, that the right type content is uploaded. Don't trust only client side validation.

More info [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.file.html)

Comment: so do I do accept: `iamge/png || iamge/jpg || iamge/gif`? why does it need the word 'image' in front?

Comment: Is there a way checking it server side, so that when I click on submit button it checks on server side and if its fine submit, else show alert?

Comment: If you want it to restrict to those three image types, yes - except it's `image/jpeg`, not `image/jpg`. The scheme it uses is a list of MIME-types - same as you may know from `text/html`, `text/javascript`  or `text/css`. I'll make a rare exception here, and refer to Wikipedia for a [partial list and explanation of MIME-types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_types).

Comment: I found an example in W3schools and made the application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Files/Files.html), Can you do this for me, is there a way it will display a alert on the page but still do the server side check, instead of going onto a new page showing the server side details of the flle?